# Automatically execute files in folder after extracting files

Tags: linux, shell, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, system

I created an extension with the folder EXTENSION containing background.js, content.js, manifest.json, auto-load.bat.
The content in the auto-load.bat file is as follows:

```
@echo off
set "EXTENSION_PATH=%~dp0"

set "EXTENSION_PATH=%EXTENSION_PATH:"=%"
set "EXTENSION_PATH=%EXTENSION_PATH:\=/%"

echo "%EXTENSION_PATH%"

taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T

start "" chrome.exe --load-extension="%EXTENSION_PATH%" --profile-directory=Default --allow-file-access-from-files

pause
```

The problem I want when the user downloads the extension's compressed file, I want when decompressing, the auto-load.bat file will be executed without winRar, that is, when decompressed, it automatically loads the extension into chrome.
Please help me!!!

I used WinRar's service to create an exe file and run it after extracting with the auto-load.bat file, but if the user downloads it and doesn't have the decompression software on their computer, it doesn't work.

Comment: In what respect is your question related to _linux_? BTW, if you someone downloads a compressed file and does not have the software for decompressing, he is out of luck. The best you can do is to also send him the compressions software (or to pack the thing you want to deliver into a self-extracting archive).